# How to find element without id selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My goal: is to automate a boring task on github

What: I want to click on "add file" and than "create new file"
[image]

I am not sure how to get the element without an id
[image]

Comment: Use  ```driver.find_element_by_class_name```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no id or the element has dynamic id, use XPATH. Using class is not ideal, since the class will possibly reused by many other elements.

In this case, use this XPATH: `//summary[.//span[contains(text(),"Add file")]]`

Best practice: use fluent wait

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, '//summary[.//span[contains(text(),"Add file")]]')
        ))
```

Read docs about explicit/fluent wait: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Answer (score 0):

You could try `driver.find_element_by_xpath("[xpath goes here]")`

If you want to read more, here are the official docs for [locating elements.](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started_with_webdriver/locating_elements/)

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdirver

#define your executable path 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable path="  ") 
browser.get("**")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("put your copied xpath here")
```

Comment: you can also use by_class